# Understand updating a row the listview

Tags: android, listview, row

I found this method to update a row in a listview. I need someone to explain to me how to implement this method. If I implement in my adapter class or activity in my class, also I know from where I get the index parameter. what I need is to go through list item one by one and compare the value of a TextView in the item with the value I get from another activity, if they are equal make it active.I have already implemented a . I hope I explained correctly thanks in advance to all.

```
 private void updateView(int index){
    View v = yourListView.getChildAt(index - 
        yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
       return;

    TextView someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
    someText.setText("Hi! I updated you manually!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the array adapter Item 
you have something like 
`Adapter adapter = new Adapter` (Receive a `list` of your data let's call `list`)

in order to modify the view with updated information just modify the list item and then call 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` that is going to be reflected on the `UI` if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This call goes in what ever class you're using your `listview` in (an activity in your case I guess). 
It basically lets you simply find a view (or list item) you're looking for and update its children layout elements directly from the activity as opposed to updating the data source in the `adapter`.

Depending on the nature of your feature it might be a better idea to update the datasource instead of manipulating the view directly.

On a different note, consider using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need good sample code/project to understand and implement ListView with supporting data. One good webpage is @ [Using lists in Android (ListView)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Snippet of code in the webpage:

```
public void run() {
   list.remove(item);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
}
```

Notes:

- The sample code uses `remove`(). Instead you can call `add`() of ArrayList.
- You need to use an **Adapter**. The tutorial uses the simple ArrayAdapter. Read up on it.
- After adding rows into an ArrayList, call `notifyDataSetChanged`() of the Adapter, as seen in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering and sorry for my bad English, and I got to do what I wanted. What I wanted was access item by item in the list until you find the item sought and then working.Then I share the code that works for me

```
public void seleccionarComprobante(Bundle bundle)
{
    int inicio=lista_comp.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int fin = adapter.getCount();
    Log.i("fatanumInicio",""+inicio);
    Log.i("fatanumFin",""+fin);
    for (int i=inicio; i<fin;i++)
    {

        View view = adapter.getView(i, null, lista_comp);
        if(view!=null)
        {
            TextView nf = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_rp_comprobantes_num_fiscal);
            if(nf.getText().toString().equals(bundle.getString("num_fiscal")))
                view.setSelected(true);
        }

    }
}
```